# We want to customize our System Workflow Messages for Contribution Receipts

Tags: wordpress

We want to customize our System Workflow Messages for Contribution Receipts using custom tokens. The tokens need to retrieve an id from a custom field on the Contribution. Using either the `hook_civicrm_tokenValues()` or the new Token Processor events, do not provide us with the Contribution ID.

Is there a trick to using the Token Processor approach, or do we need to use overrides to alter how Core is dispatching the token events?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CiviCRM Stackexchange.

You can use the below code in your tokenvalue or token processor hook for contribution receipts.

```
$contributionID = CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton()->get_template_vars('contributionID');
```

> Note: To call tokenvalue hook from your extension, the extension needs
> to have tokens present in the extension.

Comment: This seems to work for the deprecated hook_civicrm_TokenValues.
Are you sure it can also work in the TokenProcessor event?

Legacy hook will continue to work for some time I expect, but it would be great to future-proof this customization.

Comment: Yes it should also work in tokenprocessor as well

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error and consulting the source: here is how we retrieved the Contribution ID from the TokenProcessor Context:

```
function handle_evaluate_tokens(\Civi\Token\Event\TokenValueEvent $e) {
  $tp = $e->getTokenProcessor();
  $context_contrib = $tp->getContextValues('contributionId');
  $contribution_id = array_pop($context_contrib); // unbox;
...
}
```